# Why it were conjectured that $e^{e^{^e{^{79}}}}$ is not an integer only for $n=79$ ? any non trivial characterization?

Tags: prime-numbers, exponentiation, power-towers

I'm confused that why exactly and what is the reason to conjecture that  $e^{e^{^e{^{79}}}}$ [is not integer](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/is_skewes_number_e_e_e_79_an_integer) , why not for example with $n=87$ or any other prime $p$ ?Is this number special ? or is there any non trivial characterization to choose $n=79$ ?

Comment: Can you cite where this claim was made?

Comment: look [here](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/is_skewes_number_e_e_e_79_an_integer)

Comment: By your link, the reason why this is conjectured is because [Skewes Number is important for other reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number)

Comment: Skewes' number is independently interesting, so I suppose somebody was thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that $e^{e^{e^n}}$ is an integer, or for that matter algebraic, for any integer $n$.  There is certainly nothing special  about $79$, except that $e^{e^{e^{79}}}$ happens to arise in
a certain estimate.